# Alt Gr key not recognised on Ubuntu 22.04 (Swedish keyboard)

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on Virtual Box and my Alt Gr is not recognized. I am using a Swedish keyboard and it is particularly painful as I can't write '@' for example.
I tried changing the layout to US but the key is still not recognized. I also tried with a different physical keyboard and the issue is the same.

Any clue how can I fix this ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Hmm.. I missed the `kubuntu` tag. Then I'm not sure that the command I suggested applies.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I don't know if the command is supposed to work or not on `kubuntu` but it responds with `@as []`.

Comment: On Ubuntu that would tell us something, but on Kubuntu (KDE) I think that XKB options settings are handled differently. I don't have access to a Kubuntu installation ATM. Hopefully somebody who has is able to help.

Comment: I guess, when you execute this `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` command, the system ask you which key should act as `AltGr`.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I tried to use `keyboard-configuration` and chose right alt as AltgGr`key but it didn't worked. I tried to chose "default for the keyboard layout" and it didn't work either. I also tried normal keyboard layout and "no dead-key" layout.

Comment: @Mehdi, thank you for the confirmation, not many people love Kubuntu. The Unity will become an official flavor from 22.10. It is good as Xubuntu, my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install Xubuntu on VMware and the keyboard works fine. I guess this is not an issue from the OS but from the VM. Sad to be unable to use open source software.